# How to map Datasources in Wildfly using deployment descriptors

Tags: java, database, deployment, wildfly-10

My question is: How do I map a datasource to a specific jndi-name configured inside wildfly so that multiple deployed .war-files each can use their own specific datasource. The mapping should take place at deployment so that a configuration inside wildfly and the specific project is sufficient.

We got a project which supports multi-tenancy. The structure is as follows:

```
customerSpecificProject
|-- ui (generic)
  |----database (generic)
  |----services (generic)
  |----etc...
```

In the database-project a standard datasource is specified which goes by a standard jndi-name *java:/xyzDS*. Since we migrated from tomcat to wildfly we want to make use of the ability to host multiple applications in our AS.

To achieve this we have to map the *java:/xyzDS* to the datasources defined in the standalone.xml:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:4.0">
        <datasources>
            <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/customer1DS" pool-name="c1DS" enabled="true" use-ccm="true">
               ...
            </datasource>
            <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/customer2DS" pool-name="c2DS" enabled="true" use-ccm="true">
                ...
            </datasource>
```

Therefore we tried to use the *jboss-web.xml* located in the *WEB-INF* folder of our customerProject:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
  http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee
  http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-web_5_1.xsd">
  <resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>java:/xyzDS</res-ref-name>
    <jndi-name>java:/customer1DS</jndi-name>
  </resource-ref>
</jboss-web>
```

*persistence.xml* inside the database-Project:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<persistence version="2.1"
  xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence                              
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="xyzDB" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>java:/xyzDS</jta-data-source>
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>...</class>
    ...
    <class>...</class>
    <shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>
    <validation-mode>NONE</validation-mode>
    <properties>
        <property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="static" />
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

It does not seem to be working. I talked to a colleague who had a similar issue and resolved it in the corresponding way for a *websphere* AS. I do not know if the problem resides in the structure having a nested databaseProject inside another lib (ui) for the actual customerProject or if it is caused by bad configuration.

Also we use the @Resource Annotation inside some DAOs:

```
@Resource(lookup = "java:/xyzDS")
private DataSource dataSource;
```

Maybe the mapping works but not for the annotations inside the compiled DAOs? But I do not understand why that should not work.

Current Error in Stacktrace:

> 11:18:20,839 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("full-replace-deployment") failed - address: ([]) - failure description: {
>       "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"xyz.war\".INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"xyz.war\".INSTALL: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"xyz.war\"
>       Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WFLYEE0047: Incompatible conflicting binding at java:/xyzDS source: lookup (java:/customer1DS)"},

Edit: Already tried adding:

```
<property name="wildfly.jpa.twophasebootstrap" value="false"/>
```

To persistence.xml

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the question/answer in [wildfly-development.1055759.n5.nabble.com](http://wildfly-development.1055759.n5.nabble.com/How-to-deal-with-resource-refs-when-deploying-JPA-container-managed-entity-managers-WFLY-2841-td5713471.html)? In this exchange, it was determined that the persistence unit needed a hint in the form of

```
<property name="wildfly.jpa.twophasebootstrap" value="false"/>
```

I don't know if this is applicable in your case, but is worth looking at.

Comment: Sadly I already tried to add that property (forgot to mention it - sorry) and it did not resolve to issue. Thank you anyway.